# How to insert an array into an array of arrays?

Tags: raku

How could I insert an array into an array of arrays?

In Perl I would do it this way:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @aoa = ( [ 'a', 'A' ], [ 'c', 'C' ] );
splice( @aoa, 1, 0, [ 'b', 'B' ] );
print Dumper \@aoa;
```

(In Raku `splice` flattens the replacement)

Comment: The following seems to work `@aoa.splice( 1, 0, [$[ 'b', 'B' ]] )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
my @aoa = ([1,2],[5,6]);
my @arr = 3,4;
splice(@aoa, 1, 0, [@arr,]); # or splice(@aoa, 1, 0, [[3, 4],]);
say @aoa.raku;
```